# Why isn't my Handler working?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

When I go to run the app everything seems fine but when I press the Start Button it doesnt display Hello I even tried to set text before the thread and it still didnt work. Why would this be happening?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Handler mHandler;
Button enter;
Button start;
```

TextView display;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    display =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Display);

    mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            String string = bundle.getString("myKey");
            display.setText(string);

        }
    };
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.enter:
        break;
    case R.id.start:
         Thread setText = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                Message msg= Message.obtain();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String dateString;
                dateString = "Hello";
                bundle.putString("myKey", dateString);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }



        };
        setText.start();
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have u got aby error?

Comment: No the issue is when I run the code then press the start button nothing happens it should update the text view to say hello but doesn't locate doesn't report anything wrong .

Comment: add some logging like "sending message", "handling message" etc

Comment: why use Handler, why not just change it?

Comment: @Gina its probably some kind of test or something

Comment: i thought changine ui, should use runOnUiThread

Comment: This is the code I found on google and this is so I can learn how handler work

Comment: i think Dakota is just learning anout Threads, Handlers, HandlerThreads etc...

Comment: did you do sone logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't register Listeners on your enter/start button in the onCreate() method. Just call f.e.:

```
enter.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Oh wow I totally forgot about that. And here I thought it was a handler problem. Thank you for pointing that out.